# SAS EG: Excluding a data set

Tags: csv, import, sas

I'm trying to exclude a list of individuals that show up in the tables named - clmspull and enroll. The point is to exclude those with diabetes because we are looking for those who have gotten diabetes *screenings*.

I saved the list as a permanent data set called "diabexc".  I know I do a merge somewhere, for ex:

`data excdiab; /*new data set that will exclude the diabetics*/
     merge diabexc (IN=a) clmspull (IN=b) enroll (IN=c); 
     by edipn; 
run;`

I'm not sure if this is right, I feel like I'm on the right track....We just want these people removed from the data.

This is due today so I am frantic. Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

something like below by using  if a = 1 and b = 0 and c = 0 from your code after merge statement. you can also use  if a  and not  (b or c) instead. this means  records from first dataset which are not in second or third datasets.

> ```
> data diabexc;
>   input edipn ;
>  datalines;
>  1
>  2
>  3
>  4
>  ;
> ```

```
 data clmspull;
 input edipn ;
 datalines;
 3
 5
 ;

data enroll;
input edipn ;
datalines;
2
6
;

data excdiab; /*new data set that will exclude the diabetics*/
 merge diabexc (IN=a) clmspull (IN=b) enroll (IN=c); 
 by edipn; 
if a = 1 and b = 0 and c = 0;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use subqueries in proc sql :

```
proc sql ;
  create table excdiab as
  select *
  from diabexc
  where epidn ^in(select epidn from clmspull)
    and epidn ^in(select epidn from enroll)
  ;
quit ;
```